# Unable to build enterprise.jar and metadata.jar

Tags: apex, metadata-api, wsc

I am trying to build the enterprise and metadata jar files, but I am not successful. I have seen many similar posts but seem to be having a separate issue.

I have downloaded the rhino package, the file ST-4.0.jar , as well as the api version 37 jar file, and I am getting this error when I do this compilation:

```
SaulBrodskysMBP:src saulbrodsky$ java -classpath force-wsc-37.0.jar:js-1.7R2.jar:ST-4.0.jar com.sforce.ws.tools.wsdlc metadata.wsdl metadata.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/antlr/runtime/CharStream
at com.sforce.ws.tools.wsdlc.run(wsdlc.java:149)
at com.sforce.ws.tools.wsdlc.main(wsdlc.java:71)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.antlr.runtime.CharStream
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
... 2 more
```

[[ UPDATE ]]

```
SaulBrodskysMBP:src saulbrodsky$ java -classpath force-wsc-37.0.jar:js-1.7R2.jar:ST-4.0.jar:antlr-4.5.3-complete.jar com.sforce.ws.tools.wsdlc metadata.wsdl metadata.jar
[WSC][wsdlc.main:71]Generating Java files from schema ...
[WSC][wsdlc.main:71]Generated 732 java files.
[WSC][wsdlc.main:71]Compiling to target 1.6... 
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
/var/folders/yq/t9c7k4_57hjcxhwfj_m2x1980000gn/T/wsc-scratch3639753563837329210tmp/com/sforce/soap/metadata/Error.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
    private com.sforce.soap.metadata.ExtendedErrorDetails[] extendedErrorDetails = new com.sforce.soap.metadata.ExtendedErrorDetails[0];
                                    ^
  symbol:   class ExtendedErrorDetails
  location: package com.sforce.soap.metadata
/var/folders/yq/t9c7k4_57hjcxhwfj_m2x1980000gn/T/wsc-scratch3639753563837329210tmp/com/sforce/soap/metadata/Error.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
    public com.sforce.soap.metadata.ExtendedErrorDetails[] getExtendedErrorDetails() {
                                   ^
  symbol:   class ExtendedErrorDetails
  location: package com.sforce.soap.metadata
/var/folders/yq/t9c7k4_57hjcxhwfj_m2x1980000gn/T/wsc-scratch3639753563837329210tmp/com/sforce/soap/metadata/Error.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
    public void setExtendedErrorDetails(com.sforce.soap.metadata.ExtendedErrorDetails[] extendedErrorDetails) {
                                                                ^
  symbol:   class ExtendedErrorDetails
  location: package com.sforce.soap.metadata
/var/folders/yq/t9c7k4_57hjcxhwfj_m2x1980000gn/T/wsc-scratch3639753563837329210tmp/com/sforce/soap/metadata/Error.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
    private com.sforce.soap.metadata.ExtendedErrorDetails[] extendedErrorDetails = new com.sforce.soap.metadata.ExtendedErrorDetails[0];
                                                                                                               ^
  symbol:   class ExtendedErrorDetails
  location: package com.sforce.soap.metadata
/var/folders/yq/t9c7k4_57hjcxhwfj_m2x1980000gn/T/wsc-scratch3639753563837329210tmp/com/sforce/soap/metadata/Error.java:37: error: cannot find symbol
        setExtendedErrorDetails((com.sforce.soap.metadata.ExtendedErrorDetails[])__typeMapper.readObject(__in, extendedErrorDetails__typeInfo, com.sforce.soap.metadata.ExtendedErrorDetails[].class));
                                                         ^
  symbol:   class ExtendedErrorDetails
  location: package com.sforce.soap.metadata
/var/folders/yq/t9c7k4_57hjcxhwfj_m2x1980000gn/T/wsc-scratch3639753563837329210tmp/com/sforce/soap/metadata/Error.java:37: error: cannot find symbol
        setExtendedErrorDetails((com.sforce.soap.metadata.ExtendedErrorDetails[])__typeMapper.readObject(__in, extendedErrorDetails__typeInfo, com.sforce.soap.metadata.ExtendedErrorDetails[].class));
                                                                                                                                                                       ^
  symbol:   class ExtendedErrorDetails
  location: package com.sforce.soap.metadata
6 errors
1 warning
Error: Failed to compile
```

I don't understand why it's compiling to 1.6 when I have Java 1.7 installed.

How can I change that?

Comment: Don't agree that this is off-topic: calling the Salesforce API from Java is a very common requirement and [WSC](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Introduction_to_the_Force.com_Web_Services_Connector) is a Salesforce tool provided to help with that.

Comment: Its not giving me any error, but it still says 'compiling to target 1.6' even though i have 1.7 java installed on my system. How can make this to compile to 1.7? [WSC][wsdlc.main:71]Generating Java files from schema ...
[WSC][wsdlc.main:71]Generated 805 java files.
[WSC][wsdlc.main:71]Compiling to target 1.6... warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6

Answer (score 1):

A `NoClassDefFoundError` is generally caused by a JAR being missing so the class can't be found. In this case it appears to be ANTLR so download and add that JAR to your classpath.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered a similar error (ExtendedErrorDetails) while using WSC 37.0 jar file and when I have replaced it with the latest 38.0.3 WSC jar file in the -classpath the issue is resolved. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.antlr.org/download/antlr-4.7.2-complete.jar download the ANTLR jar and use this. It resolved my issue.

I have used the following command:

```
java -classpath .\force-wsc-45.0.0;.\antlr-4.7.2-complete.jar;.\js.jar;.\ST-4.1.jar;.\js.jar;.\tools.jar com.sforce.ws.tools.wsdlc enterprise.wsdl enterprise.jar
```

All of my jar files are in the same directory. Also, do not save enterprise.wsdl with .xml extension, instead save this file with .wsdl extension.

Comment: I am getting java.lang.NullPointerException when generating partner jar. can you help....